# How can I take input of different types of data and output text based on them?

Tags: java

I have an input file with lines like this:

```
add_student John 18 180 2014
```

Where John is the name, 18 is the age, 180 is the height, and 2014 is the year of admission.

How can I take these values from the input file, and output something like this in a separate output file, for example:

```
Student's name: John
Student's Age: 18
Student's Year of Admission: 2014
```

Comment: read the file, split the string using the ``split()`` method. That's all.

Comment: I am a beginner, it's not that simple to me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Add your codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this code. I tried to add some comments. Hopefully it would be clear for you.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[]args){

        try {
        // Read the txt file
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new  File("data.txt"));
        // Loop through all the lines in the file
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            // Store the line
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            // Split the line by (spaces)
            String[] studentInfo = line.split(" "); // This will produce the following array {"add_student","john",18,180,2014}
            // Print the data
            System.out.println("Student's name : " + studentInfo[1]);
            System.out.println("Student's age : " + studentInfo[2]);
            System.out.println("Student's height : " + studentInfo[3]);
            System.out.println("Student's year of admission : " + studentInfo[4]);
            }

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        // Do whatever you want in case the file not found
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }

    }
```